# where can i get different cypher query commands?

Tags: timestamp, neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j. i have just installed and practised a few code present in the guide provided by their official website.
I need assistance on where to get more codes for Neo4j or cypher. I have an idea only on the queries present in this link [Neo4j cypher cheat sheet](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/1.9/)

where can i get idea for inserting a timestamp and varoius other function?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO and Neo4j. The starting point is the [Neo4j documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/). There you choose which version of Neo4j you want to learn. 1.9.5 is at this point the last stable release, but 2.0 will be released very soon, and I recommend starting there. That means that you find the manual pages regarding cypher [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-query-lang.html) and specifically the timestamp function [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-timestamp). All the grammar that is summarized in the cheat sheet is explained in a little more detail in those pages and there are examples of use.

Next I recommend the [learn cypher](http://www.neo4j.org/learn/cypher) page, which is an interactive tutorial based on the online [Neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org/). The console is a keeper, here you can go to create small sample graphs and test out your cypher queries, and it is particularly useful when you want to ask questions on SO about a specific modelling problem or query: create a sample of your data and model in the console, click "Share", copy the link and include it with your question here. It is much easier to answer a question when there is a shared graph to look at and you will likely get faster and higher quality answers that way.

Then install [Neo4j server](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server.html), run it and explore the new [Neo4j browser](http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/10/neo4j-200-m06-introducing-neo4js-browser.html). It contains similar tutorials to the "learn cypher" page above and has a similar ui to Neo4j console (but much prettier). Since the changes you make to your database in the browser are persistent, you can explore cypher in much more depth and create more advanced models. When you run the browser the first time you will get the option to take a quick tour which will show you how to use it.

Then remains to click the [cypher] tag here at SO and read all the questions and answers, follow the [Neo4j blog](http://blog.neo4j.org/) and look at any graph gists posted there (such as [this](http://gist.neo4j.org/?github-neo4j-contrib/gists//other/SocialNetworkGraph.adoc)), identify the people know cypher well and read what they write on their blogs (there are several, examples are [1](http://wes.skeweredrook.com/cypher/), [2](http://maxdemarzi.com/category/cypher/) and [3](http://blog.armbruster-it.de/tag/cypher/)).

Comment: thank you jjaderberg. i will practise what you have told and further post questions if i have any other doubts. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j has provided very well documentation on their official document site::

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/index.html

Read cypher queries section.
You can try cypher online using link:::

http://www.neo4j.org/learn/try

Answer (score 0):

The Cypher cheat sheet is nice if you've understood the concepts and need a reference nearby your desktop.
The reference manual has a [extensive section](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-query-lang.html) on Cypher teaching you all the details. This covers the timestamp() function as well.

Neo Technology offers 1 day training events focussing on Cypher call "Neo4j Intro". Check out the [schedule](http://www.neotechnology.com/events/) to see if there one in your region.